# Is it possible to rotate element, but not its content with css3?

Tags: html, css

I have the following element

```
<a href="#" class="some_class">Test Text Here</a>
```

and this element has light blue background and some padding. Today I came across one small challenge: I know we can rotate element, however its contents are also rotated. What I was trying to achieve looks like this:

[image]

So the element itself is slightly rotated, however its contents stay in place. Is this achievable just with CSS3? I tried playing around with several nested elements, however by rotating their parent element all child elements rotated as well. Also can this be done with single element, like example stated above?

Comment: don't nest element, just superpose the text over the blue div

Comment: @Sebas wow, first time I hear about superpose, let me do a some research on this

Comment: Another option is to have a nested child with the text, apply the rotation to the parent, and then apply the reverse rotation to the child. (Though I prefer Sebas's approach of just doing no nesting at all.)

Comment: @Sebas Ah I see, do you mean to, say wrap text in a span tag and make it absolutely positioned? But is there a way without using additional elements? As I don't understand what you mean by superposing text, can you expand on this please.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KWbwP/).

Comment: With your proposed markup I would suggest against super-imposing the text over your link.  The text needs to be nested inside your anchor tag for SEO purposes.  If you follow the super-impose method then you would put your blue box on a div instead.

Regardless of which way you do it, I don't know of a way to do it without extra elements, and I prefer the nested solution in almost all cases, especially if you are using links.

Comment: There's no additional element, nested or siblings there are 2 elements. Apply same positionning to both and that's it. To ease the job you could use the help of a common parent and fill 100% of it with both children

Comment: About SEO @Michael said, we can still put the text in the link but hide them (using similar color, transparency, etc) while superimposing it's sibling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, If you wrap the text in a span, then set the span to `position: absolute`, and `transform` it the equal amount in the opposite direction to "default" it.

I would suggest *against* super-imposing the text over your link in your proposed case above, as you want the text to be *INSIDE* the anchor tag for SEO purposes.

So... I rotated `<a>` 10 degree's clockwise, and rotated the `<span>` 10 degree's counter-clockwise.

*****ALTERNATIVELY** - You could also set the span to display: block; and drop the absolute positioning.  It depends on your use case.  Absolute positioning it, in this case, would allow you to move the text around with a little more control.

http://jsfiddle.net/B95xa/

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-10deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Very useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options that I am aware of:

1. Make them separate elements and just rotate the background image/div. This method would work if you need to animate the rotation.
2. If you are using an image, save the background image as pre-skewed.