# Fix the text while rotating the parent div

Tags: html, css, rotation

Please see below HTML

```
<div id="parent">
   <p>something</p>
</div>
```

When we are rotating the div obviously the text in it also rotate, can we prevent it??
Rotate the div but not content in it...

Comment: Here You have solutions of your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656394/is-it-possible-to-rotate-element-but-not-its-content-with-css3

Comment: In my case, am using jquery touch to rotate the div with fingers

Comment: Text within rotating div will definitely rotate, use 2 elements. 1 for rotating div and 1 for text. Adjust layout with positions.

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward approach, just rotate back the inner element.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpwchqpf/

```
#parent {
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
#parent p {
    color: blue;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-30deg);

}
```